# could not delete collection rows: The column index is out of range

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, exception

I have following Hibernate classes:

'Skill' has many 'SkillTranslation' which extends 'ResourceTranslation'

Skill:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "skill")
@ToString
@Getter
@Setter
public class Skill {
    @Id
    private String id;
   
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "key", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Set<SkillTranslation> localizedDescription;
}
```

SkillTranslation:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "skill_translation")
public class SkillTranslation extends ResourceTranslation{
}
```

ResourceTranslation:

```
@ToString
@Getter
@Setter
@MappedSuperclass
@IdClass(ResourceTranslation.PK.class)
public class ResourceTranslation implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String key;
    @Id
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Locale locale;
    @Column(length = 10000)
    private String value;


    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public static class PK implements Serializable {
        private String key;
        @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
        private Locale locale;
    }
}
```

The problem occurs when I try to update an existing skill(initial version has 3 localized description and new one has only 2)

Stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not delete collection rows: [hidden.Skill.localizedDescription#71f13be5-c692-46d3-875c-62d0905bb5ba]; SQL [update skill_translation set key=null where key=? and locale=?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not delete collection rows: [hidden.Skill.localizedDescription#71f13be5-c692-46d3-875c-62d0905bb5ba]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:302)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:255)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:538)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:633)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:386)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691)
    at hidden.ImportSkillsService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2d832c5f.importSkills(<generated>)
    at hidden.syncAll(hidden.java:21)
    at hidden.job.RefreshAllJob.refresh(RefreshAllJob.java:22)
    at hidden.BaseRefreshJob.run(BaseRefreshJob.java:33)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not delete collection rows: [hidden.Skill.localizedDescription#71f13be5-c692-46d3-875c-62d0905bb5ba]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.deleteRows(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1509)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.CollectionUpdateAction.execute(CollectionUpdateAction.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478)
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:348)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1363)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:454)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3213)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2381)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:447)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:534)
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 3, number of columns: 2.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.SimpleParameterList.bind(SimpleParameterList.java:65)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.SimpleParameterList.setStringParameter(SimpleParameterList.java:128)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.bindString(PgPreparedStatement.java:1019)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.setString(PgPreparedStatement.java:343)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.setString(PgPreparedStatement.java:330)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.setString(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarcharTypeDescriptor$1.doBind(VarcharTypeDescriptor.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.convert.internal.NamedEnumValueConverter.writeValue(NamedEnumValueConverter.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.type.EnumType.nullSafeSet(EnumType.java:262)
    at org.hibernate.type.CustomType.nullSafeSet(CustomType.java:170)
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.nullSafeSet(ComponentType.java:365)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.nullSafeSet(EntityType.java:280)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.writeElementToWhere(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:959)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.deleteRows(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1473)
    ... 35 common frames omitted
```

Hibernate version: 5.4.20.Final

Comment: `when I try to update an existing skill` - please show how you do it.

Comment: `Locale` is not an enum, so you can't use `@Enumerated`. Remove that annotation. It will be mapped as string anyway by Hibernate. Also, I think you mixed up the order of columns. Use `@JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "key")`

Comment: @ChristianBeikov, Locale is an internal project enum, I checked JoinColumn once again and it seems to be valid, "key" from ResourceTranslation references "id" in Skill

Comment: Hmm you are right. You should create an issue in the issue tracker(https://hibernate.atlassian.net) with a test case(https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/blob/master/orm/hibernate-orm-5/src/test/java/org/hibernate/bugs/JPAUnitTestCase.java) that reproduces the issue.

Comment: If someone reads this: I've faced similar issue but with Composite embedded id. Resolved it by specifying `insertable = false, updatable = false`.